# Bounds on $L^2$ and $L^{\infty}$ norms in terms of $H^1$-seminorms for functions attaining a zero in a domain.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

We have the following result in one dimension:

If $f\in C^1([a,b])$ attains a zero in $[a,b]$, then

$$| f  |_2 \leq (b-a) | f'  |_2$$

and

$$ | f |_{\infty} \leq (b-a)^{1/2} | f' |_2$$

Is there a generalisation to higher dimensions for a function that attains a zero somewhere in a domain $\Omega$? Thanks :)

Comment: There are similar Poincare inequalities in higher dimensions that apply to functions that have trace $0$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality.

Comment: Hint: If $f(z) = 0$ then $f(s) = \int_z^s f'(t) dt$.

Comment: @EricThoma Yes I know about those, but I'm assuming that they attain a zero not zero mean.

Comment: Fair play, that was easy to prove, ill edit that out, still looking for a generalisation

Comment: This is not possible in higher dimensions. However, you might get $\|f\|_\infty \le C \, \|\nabla f\|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ for $p > n$.